# What does "he is said to have assumed" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I found the following sentence very difficult to understand. There are actually two parts I didn't understand.

- Since Christopher Columbus began his journey to America with the intent of finding an alternate route to Southeast Asia, **he is said to have assumed** that the people he came into contact with **upon reaching land** were Indians.*

The link of this sentence is, http://www.wisegeek.org/why-are-native-americans-called-indians.htm. **See first paragraph of the essay**.

Does **he is said to have assumed* mean that *people say that Christopher Columbus assumed that*. I asked this question because the usage of this term is very difficult to understand since this usage behavior does not exist in my native language.

Does *upon reaching land* mean India (a nation) or South East Asia?

Comment: Yes you are right. You have answered your own question.

Comment: Except that *upon reaching land* obviously doesn't refer to India or South East Asia, since where he actually landed was ***America*** (specifically, [the Bahamas archipelago, on an island he named San Salvador](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus)).

Answer (score 1):

As Man_From_India says, you have understood *is said to have assumed* correctly. More generally *SUBJ BE said to VERB<sup>infinitive</sup>* may be paraphrased as *people say that SUBJ VERB<sup>finite</sup>*.

The preposition phrase *upon VERB<sup>pres.ppl</sup>* may be paraphrased *at the time SUBJ VERB<sup>finite</sup>*, where *SUBJ* is the subject of the clause which the preposition phrase modifies:

> the people he came in contact with upon reaching land = the people he came in contact with at the time he reached land
>
> You will receive your inheritance upon attaining the age of 21. = You will receive your inheritance at the time you reach the age of 21.